# handle coldfusion complex type in .NET

Tags: .net, arrays, web-services, coldfusion

I try to send to a .net webservice an array of defined components from coldfusion but i get an error and i don't know how to handle the complex type in .net method.
My component is:

```
<cfcomponent name = "Person" output="false">
    <cfproperty name="name" type="string" />
    <cfproperty name="surname" type="string" />
</cfcomponent>

<cfset personArray = ArrayNew(1) />
<cfloop from="1" to="10" index="i">
    <cfset personArray[#i#] = createObject("component", "person")>
    <cfset personArray[#i#].name = "personname" />
    <cfset personArray[#i#].surname = "personsurname" />
</cfloop>

<cfscript>
     service = CreateObject("webservice", "service.asmx?WSDL");
     r = service.SendArray(#personArray#,0);
</cfscript>
```

The method from .net looks like this:

```
public string SendArray(Object[] personList, int numberid)
{   
    ...
}
```

The error is Message Content: Web service operation SendArray with parameters {[[(Component=person)], ... }  cannot be found. If i modify and call the method SendArray(0) without complex type the method is call correctly. I don't know how to define and take the array in .net.

Comment: Word of advice, you don't usually need # # around variables in assignments, e.g. this is fine: <cfset personArray[i].name = "personname" />

Answer (score 3):

First, some errors with semantics:

You created an array with ArrayNew(1), but you are coercing each index of the array into a Struct implicitly by jamming keys on the end, which changes its type (since ColdFusion is dynamically typed). Consider:

```
<cfloop from="1" to="10" index="i">
    <cfset personArray[i] = StructNew() />
    <cfset personArray[i].object = createObject("component", "person")>
    <cfset personArray[i].name = "personname" />
    <cfset personArray[i].surname = "personsurname" />
</cfloop>
```

Now, personArray remains a true array, rather than being coerced into a Struct before passing.

There is a much larger issue, however...

Web service messaging via SOAP isn't designed to facilitate the support of passing complex business objects from point-to-point; this is a common misconception that confuses and frustrates developers that are just getting started with SOA. This isn't a problem native to ColdFusion and/or .NET--this is a low-level SOAP limitation.

Let's assume for the moment that there was a way to do what you wanted to, and in your "Person" component above, which within the confines of ColdFusion, exists as a complete object with its own properties and methods, some of which involve the maintenance of state (say, isPersonLoggedIn()), and internally, that is managed by the functionality present in ColdFusion (ie. the automatically handling of CFID & CFTOKEN, the access into the shared SESSION scope, etc.)

Now, if you were hypothetically able to pass a logged in "Person" object over to a .NET application--and then, that .NET application decides to call isPersonLoggedIn() on its end--how would it possible know how to do that? It has no understanding of CFID or CFTOKEN, no concept of shared memory (or at least, how ColdFusion expects to handle shared memory)--and nothing exists to translate those concepts across the wire, since (of course) the maintenance of said state exists within the physical boundary of the ram on the CF server in the first place.

Although a wild analogy, it should hopefully paint a clearer picture as to why you cannot do what you are attempting to--pass a complex business object across the wire via a mechanism, which (at its heart) is a stream of XML.

When you develop SOAP-based services (consumers & producers), you need to think in terms of simple values: Look up this user's name. Give me this employee's phone number. Tell me how many records are in this database for a given Department ID.

As opposed to: Take this business object which represents all the functionality of we can perform on a "Person" in the confines of our application that no other application in the world knows about--and magically hand that to any application and expect it to behave in the same fashion.

Take away points:

1. Consider rethinking your design. Rather than passing the Person object itself, design methods that will only look for certain discrete values based upon the person object (ie. PersonID, PersonName, NumberOfPeople, etc.)
2. Refer to [this chart on data types for web-service communication in ColdFusion](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=webservices_26.html).

Otherwise, you are going to be asked--by the people who build the .NET service--for a lot of pre-compiled classes on your end that must be integrated on their end in order to understand your business objects...and at that point, you're no longer communicating by web-services via SOAP--you're communicating by phone...with their development staff...every time a single business object changes, and you both have to re-work code.

For further reading, take a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260301/coldfusion-error-while-accessing-java-webservice/8260408#8260408) for [someone on StackOverflow that asked the reverse of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260301/coldfusion-error-while-accessing-java-webservice).